# Граф в виде списка смежностей

Tags: графы, c++, список

UPD: Переписал код и не пойму, почему вылетает на `for(j = gr[i].list.begin(); j != gr[i].list.end(); ++j)`

Сам код http://pastebin.com/aHsGD2GK

Объявляю структуры

```
struct tlist {
    int inf;
    tlist *next;
};

struct orgraph {
    int top;
    tlist *first;
};

void insert(orgraph *gr, int x, int y) {
    tlist *cur = gr[x].first;
    tlist *pr = NULL;
    tlist* now = new tlist;
    now->inf = y;
    now->next = NULL;
    while(cur != NULL) {
        pr = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if(pr == NULL) {
        gr[x].first = now;
    } 
    else {
        pr->next = now;
    }
}
```

И вроде всё хорошо, но мне нужно удалить дугу соединяющую вершины a и b. И тут я в ступоре, как поступить. Понимаю, что

```
  void delete_xy(orgraph *gr, int x, int y) {
     tlist *tmp = gr[x].first;
}
```

Ну а как же мне стереть Y ?

Comment: Если C++, почему не стандартные контейнеры, а велосипед из односвязного списка? (Из названий структур, кстати, не понятно, где у вас рёбра графа.)

Comment: Написание велосипеда часть задания

Comment: Получается мне нужно создать одну структуру и в ней хранить информацию о вершине и список смежностей в контейнере set. Я всё правильно понимаю ?

Comment: @Error, а у Вас, что - практическая задача, а не учебное упражнение?

Comment: Да, практическая задача, главное условие что бы граф был представлен в виде списка смежности.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Error](/users/4933/error)](/users/4933/error), может быть более ясная формулировка вопроса:

```
Как удалить элемент односвязного списка с заданным ключем?
```

(Ключ - это inf в структуре tlist)

поможет Вам самостоятельно ее решить?

Чуть подскажу - при удалении надо помнить адрес предыдущего элемента списка.

Еще один маленький совет: для быстрой вставки в конец списка модифицируйте структуру

```
struct orgrahp {
   int top;
   tlist *first, *last;
};
```

А еще лучше - перейдите на двусвязный список.

Answer (score 0):

Ээх, ударьте чем-нибудь вашего учителя по голове, например, книгой Страуструпа...

---

Но вы хоть опишите, какой смысл структуры `tlist`, а то без вдумчивого разбора кода непонятно.

Ну, `std::vector` там, `std::set`, или на крайний случай `std::list`. Для набора рёбер логично использовать `std::set<edge*>`, где `edge` — структура, представляющая ребро.